# "Binding" variables by reference for delayed processing in class

Tags: php, arrays, class, pointers, reference

I have a singleton of the following class. What I'm trying to achieve is collect references to various database result arrays that are called throughout the application, then finally make a single request to the database and fetch some replace values (translations) instead of doing it for every single query.

Leaving the pros and cons of this approach aside, what I can't do is the actual replacement of the "original" values (database results) that get passed to the `translate()` method by reference each time a query is sent to the DB server.

```
class Translator {

    public $translatableTables = ['content' => ['title', 'body']];
    private $table = 'translations';
    private $queue = array();

    public function translate($table, &$results)
    {
        if(!isset($this->queue[$table])) {
            $this->queue[$table] = array();
        }
        $this->queue[$table][] =& $results;
    }

    public function fetchTranslations()
    {
        foreach($this->queue as &$table) {
            foreach($table as &$results) {
                foreach($results as &$result) {
                    $result->content = 'DON\'T PANIC THIS IS A TEST';
                }
            }
        }
        var_dump($this->queue);
        // dumps just the right data, so I know it's all been collected
    }

}
```

Near the end of the request lifecycle (but before the output is generated) I'm calling the `fetchTranslations()` method on that same singleton instance.
What I expect to happen is the original values to be replaced with the string `DON'T PANIC THIS IS A TEST` but that doesn't work.

Any thoughts/ideas?

Edit: The 3 nested `foreach` loops may look bad, but that's a short version of the actual business logic in that method which is irrelevant to the problem and skipped for readability.

Edit: As it turned out I was supposed to get each `foreach` value as reference. That was a real issue with the code but after making said changes it still shows the same behavior (or to be more precise doesn't show the expected behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every one of your `foreach` are copying the arrays, because it's got multiple references to it.  [Discussion.](https://nikic.github.io/2011/11/11/PHP-Internals-When-does-foreach-copy.html)

You can `&` reference the `foreach` values or you can add keys, so that at the end you're doing `$this->queue[$i][$j][$k]->content = 'foo';`

Comment: Yes, I agree it looks bad the way it is, but it's a short version of the actual business logic in that method which is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: @Ash Ah, got it.  I suggest adding that to your OP. I've removed my comment about the O(n^3).

Comment: Your point about getting the foreach values as reference is correct. Without the `&` operator the arrays were being copied each time. However, my code still doesn't work, which is why I haven't picked an answer yet. I'll have to take some time to see if the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Having modified the foreach to iterate by reference, the problem is either in the logic missing from the OP or outside that method.  [In this example](http://3v4l.org/6HadZ), the iteration correctly sets the test string.

Comment: Indeed the issue with this part of the code were the missing & operators. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Consider this line,

```
public function translate($table, &$results)
```

It evaluates to **What changes are applied to `$results` are applied to the variable passed to that function.**

Now,

```
if(!isset($this->queue[$table])) {
    $this->queue[$table] = array();
}
$this->queue[$table][] =& $results;
```

Now, nothing is done to change the results in above code.

Now, consider the below,

```
public function fetchTranslations()
{
    foreach($this->queue as $table) {
        foreach($table as $results) {
            foreach($results as &$result) {
                $result->content = 'DON\'T PANIC THIS IS A TEST';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you passed it right, by the referance, but `$results` is going to change after all, not the `$this->queue`

If i suggest, you need to build logic again for that Class

Comment: I really don't see the point to your answer. What you're really saying that you understood my code correctly and there is a code design issue but you don't suggest a better approach.